# How do I use Salesforce's Geocodes?

Tags: visualforce, geolocation

I've already activated  "Clean Rules" Geocodes for Contact mailing Address in Salesforce. I understand from the links I've read that the geocodes don't actually show up unless through a custom field.

1. How would I then create a custom field that shows the geolocations of my contacts' mailing address?
2. My Sales people want to go on roadshows and have contacts that are close to one another show up if they show to be he Contact owner. How exactly do I achieve this? Can this be done on the UI through Geocodes?

I also saw another posting quoting below that has API code which I believe can achieve something in the lines of what I want. I'm not a developer and I don't fully grasp the  coding nor would I know how to put this inside a Visualforce page. in my case, my object would be Contacts and the geocodes would be that of the mailing Address.

```
<apex:map width="600px" height="400px" mapType="roadmap"
center="{!Account.BillingStreet},{!Account.BillingCity},{!Account.BillingState}">

    <apex:repeat value="{! MyObj__c.Addresses }" var="addr">
      <apex:mapMarker title="{! addr.Name }"
        position="{!addr.MailingStreet},{!addr.MailingCity},{!addr.MailingState}"
      />
    </apex:repeat>

 </apex:map>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Contact.MailingAddress` composite field contains `MailingLatitude` and `MailingLongitude` as fields. Same pattern applies to `Account.BillingAddress` and `Account.ShippingAddress` as well.

---

Note from the documentation on the [`<apex:mapMarker>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_mapMarker.htm) tag how the `position` attribute works:

> **Attribute Name**
>   position
>
> **Attribute Type**
>   Object
>
> **Description**
>   Specifies the location of the marker. There are several ways to define the location:
>
> - A string representing an address. For example, "1 Market Street, San Francisco, CA". The address is automatically geocoded to determine its actual latitude and longitude.
> - **A string representing a JSON object with latitude and longitude attributes that specify location coordinates. For example, "{latitude: 37.794, longitude: -122.395}"**.
> - 0 An Apex map object of type Map, with latitude and longitude keys to specify location coordinates.
>
> Note: You can have up to 10 geocoded address lookups per map. Lookups for both the center attribute of the  component and the position attribute of the  component count against this limit. To display more markers, provide position values that don't require geocoding. Locations that exceed the geocoding limit are skipped.

---

Putting it all together, you should be able to use the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:map height="800" width="800">
        <apex:mapMarker position="{latitude: {!Account.BillingLatitude}, longitude: {!Account.BillingLongitude}}" />
    </apex:map>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I've put the above code in an an APex Class and when doing a quick save I get hte following error message:

Comment: This is the error message I get when entering hte above code in the Apz controller: " Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '<' at line 1 column 0" Also once that works, do I need to put this inside a visualforce page? How? can you guide me with the code? After I do this, will I be able to to view a google map with the surrounding Contacts that have geolocations nearby the contact that I'm currently on? How can I see this?

Comment: This is the `Visualforce` markup...you don't even need `Apex`.

Comment: So I'm not quite clear then. What do I do? Do I cut and paste the above into a VisualForce page and then insert the page inside my Accounts or Contact screen? Will I then be able to see the locationso f my contacts nad accounts? I already have a Google map shoing hte location of the contactor Account which was already included out of hte box with Salesforce. What I'm wanting to do is make use of Geolocations that just came out in ord to be able to pull up all the Contact that are for example within 20 miles of hte current contact record. I'm not sure if this can be done and how?

Comment: Your comments are a bit rambling and you added a new question in there (ask that separately), but yes, you would place the markup above into a `Visualforce Page`. You would then be able to include that page on any `Page Layout` for the `Account` object.

Comment: Okay. I did manage to get a map. That worked. I put this on the Contacts page as that was what I wanted and the goecodes that i activated are under my Contact screen for now. I just changed hte word "billing" for "mailing" address which is what Contacts uses. The only thing is that the map did not show me more than one contact location. What exactly should I do to get more locations? Does it pick up all the contacts within a same account? I'd like it to pick up any closeby contact to my contact under ANY of the accounts inthe database.

Comment: You will need to ask a ***separate question*** about these tasks, as they are more involved than your initial question, which was simply how to merge geocodes into a `mapMarker`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49677/discussion-between-andrea-and-adrian-larson).